# Creating a button becomes white in Android studio (for android l design)

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop

So I'm trying to create a Button for my android app and it seems like when adding a button for Android L then the button become completely white, does anyone know if it's a bug or if I'm doing  something wrong?

[image]

My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".loginActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mm">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordfield"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userNamefield"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userNamefield"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userNamefield" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/userNamefield"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Password"
        android:labelFor="@+id/passwordfield"
        android:id="@+id/passwordfieldtxtview"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/passwordfield"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passwordfield"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Username"
        android:id="@+id/UsernametextView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/passwordfield"
        android:layout_above="@+id/passwordfield"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LoginButton"
        android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#black"
        android:background="#D1D1D1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding color property?

Comment: Yeah but i'm only able to change the text color... the whole button is still white

Comment: You may use `background_color` property.

Comment: I've done that but it's still white ,  writing #gray or hex like: #6B6B6B (tried several hexes) does nothing

Comment: I think `id:"@+id/LoginButton"` is wrong. Try removing that line and run project.

Comment: You run project after removing line?

Comment: Yeah that wasn't the problem , Seems like it's a bug(rare?) in the new android studio , i went and downloaded an older version and it worked

Answer (score 1):

you want to put the like android:textColor="#000000" this

Answer (score 0):

`android:textColor="#black"` it's wrong.

Maybe you want something like this:

`android:textColor="#333"`